# How to add a new TableRow into a LinearLayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to create multiple rows of TableRows in a LinearLayout. Here is my code so far:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum=".0"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableRow>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/aString"
    android:text="Bench Press"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/aa"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ab"
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ac"
    android:text="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:text="4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableRow>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/bString"
    android:text="Bicep Curls"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ba"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/bb"
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/bc"
    android:text="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/bd"
    android:text="4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

In that code I have two different TableRows and I'm trying to get each one in their own vertical row, but the second one is just added on to end of the first row. How do I make it so each TableRow gets it's own row? I would like to continue using LinearLayout if possible as well, that has been the only way I've made it so the different columns scale properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant add TableRow with out TableLayout.

```
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum=".0"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>`
```

.
.
.

If view want show some separater in your LinearLayout just use `<View .....`

Comment: Ahhhh I knew it'd be something simple I was missing. I thought I wouldn't be able to use "weightSum" without LinearLayout, that's why I wanted to stick with it! Thank you very much, I just needed to change from LinearLayout to TableLayout! Cheers =)